# View jitter on Beckhoff controller

Tags: twincat

On a controller with Codesys runtime, we can can see actual, maximum and minimum jitter of the processor.
We can even trace the jitter.
Is this also possible on a Beckhoff controller (with off course Twincat runtime)?

The only thing I saw was a trace for 'latency', but I suppose this is not the same as the 'jitter' shown on Codesys runtime controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Profiler function block. Check out the video: [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s5O8srtDTM)

A more detailed profiler product will be available in future: [Beckhoff Info](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/automation/twincat/texxxx-twincat-3-engineering/te1210.html)